# Commas in arguments of an array

Tags: matlab

The second argument in plot puzzles me, removed the "()" after S and no difference. What is the point of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case where `S` is a matrix, the arguments that follow are used to take a selection of the matrix in each dimension. The `:` operator is used to select entries in a range (e.g. `2:end`) and when used alone (i.e. `:`) selects all entries in a range.

The following example selects all rows (`:`) of the second column (`2`). Note that `S` and `S(:, :, 1)` in this case are identical as this array does not contain a third dimension. I believe this is also the case for your example.

```
>> S = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9]

S =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9

>> S(:, 2)

ans =

     2
     5
     8
```